How to convert the perl script unpack command in Azure Synapse expression?
`The code seems to be checking if there is any binary string it will convert to integer ?

  ``$changeNum = substr($rec, 280, 4); # 281
if(!($changeNum =~ /^[0-9]+$/))
{
    $changeNum = unpack("i*", $changeNum);
}`

`Can anyone suggest the adf expression for this ?
`
   `iif(regexMatch(substring(Column_1,281,4),'^[0-9]+$'),toInteger(substring(Column_1,281,4)),0)`


You can use the below expression in the derived column transformation to achieve your requirement.
iif(regexMatch(substring(binay_col,4,4),'^[0-9]+$'),reduce(map([4,3,2,1],multiply(power(2,#item-1),toInteger(split(reverse(substring(binay_col,4,4)),'')[#item]))),0,#acc + toInteger(#item),#result),toInteger('0'))

Result:


This is not correct I am getting the binarystring which is in the form "^@^@^@^@" and the value comes as 0 or 1 sometime.....I think we need to use some decode logic here ....as the data is coming in encode format...but perlscript tries to decode.

Not working please check the binary string means the string could be encode form....like when you see the a.out file it shows @^@^@^ like this I am getting in the feedfile....how to tranform that chnage_num field using unpack logic similar in synapse ???

Currently, there are no such encoding functions in ADF dataflow expressions. I think its better to use notebooks for these kind of transformations.
